# In AngularJS, how can I call a directive inside a controller to perform a task?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that performs some DB calls and loads content into my `$scope` accordingly. Everything works perfect. When the calls are complete I run some JS inside the controller in a call back to adjust the height and other attributes of my application. Unfortunately, I'm running this JS in multiple controllers.

I'd like to place the script into a directive so I can run the directive in the controllers callback and only have the JS live in one spot. Other than this being "the correct way" it will make upkeep much easier.

Comment: Without any code or detailed explanation, it's hard to glean what you want your end result to be. Part of me says you want a factory instead of a directive for this purpose, based on the "so I can run the directive in the controllers callback" statement ... that's not what directives do / are for.

Comment: I don't have any code since it's a general question. Normally (such as in php and js) I would just have a function called `adjustSizes()` that I call at the end of the script.

Comment: what about emitting an event (maybe on the root scope?) on a controller's side and handling it on a directive?

Answer (score 1):

When sharing code between several controllers, [use a service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Example code from AngularJS docs:

```
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
 controller('MyController', ['$scope','notify', function ($scope, notify) {
   $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
     notify(msg);
   };
 }]).
factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
   var msgs = [];
   return function(msg) {
     msgs.push(msg);
     if (msgs.length == 3) {
       win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
       msgs = [];
     }
   };
 }]);
```

Directives are for use in the HTML, not for scripting within the controllers.